# Use Linux dd to copy and read file at specified location

Tags: linux, dd

I want to use the `dd` command to write one file at any location of the hard drive and then to read the same file from this location. I need to be independent on any file system or partitioning. It seems not easy to do this. The prerequisites are:

1. In order to do this I need to be able to navigate on the hard drive. The compass would be the sectors, let's say 1 sector = 512 B.
2. The file size is, let's say 150 B. Simple text file.
3. I want to write this file starting from 2099200 sector.

I tried this:

```
sudo dd if=my.txt of=/dev/sdb obs=512 seek=2099199
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=my.txt obs=150 count=1 ibs=512 skip=2099199
```

but it is not working because I can not make it read only 150 B, because of the `ibs` count which is 512 B. I need this count in order to easily navigate on the hard drive so it must be 512 B.

Is there an easy way to handle this case with `dd`? Or maybe there is another command or way to do this? I need to be independent on any kind of file systems and partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this one to seek `bytes` `(2099199*512)` not `bs` count.

```
dd if=your.txt of=/dev/sdb count=1 bs=150 oflag=seek_bytes seek=1074789888
```

and

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=your.txt count=1 bs=150 iflag=skip_bytes skip=1074789888
```

See `man dd`.

---

Then what about:

```
dd if=your.txt of=/dev/sdb bs=1 count=150 seek=1074789888
```

and

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=your.txt bs=1 count=150 skip=1074789888
```

Comment: unfortunately my version of dd seems not having this flags.

Answer (score 0):

#### Preliminary notes

Just to be clear:

- If you "want to write this file starting from 2099200 sector" then you should use `obs=512 seek=2099200`. Sectors are numbered from 0. "Starting from sector 0" can be done with `seek=0`; "from sector 1" with `seek=1` etc.
- Commands in this answer don't include `sudo`. This is for readability. Just use `sudo` if needed.

---

#### Actual answer

I agree that after one writes data like you did, the best way to navigate while reading is to use `ibs=512`. With `count=1` you read 512 bytes and `obs` cannot affect this. Retrieving exactly 150 bytes from these 512 is in fact quite easy:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb ibs=512 skip=2099199 | dd of=my.txt ibs=1 count=150
```

Notes:

- The first `dd` doesn't need `count=1`. If it tries to write to the pipe after the second `dd` exits, it will get a signal (`SIGPIPE`) and exit as well. And if you need the second `dd` to process e.g. 9999 bytes, it's enough to change the `count` there. You don't need to calculate `count` for the first `dd`. The pipeline mechanism will let it know if its output loses the receiver.
- Another way is `… | head -c 150` but this is not POSIX.
- In general `dd` may read partial blocks, therefore I used `ibs=1 count=150`, not `ibs=150 count=1` (compare [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278465/108618)). The latter would *probably* work in this case, still in general you need to remember `dd` may read blocks smaller than `ibs` and each of them still increases the count. `iflag=fullblock` helps, but this feature is not required by POSIX and your `dd` may not support it. The first `dd` should be safe despite `ibs=512` for two reasons:

  - The input file is seekable, so `dd` just calculates and requests the proper offset. If it read from a pipe, it would need to actually read 2099199 blocks and in general any of them could be partial, so the amount of discarded data might be less than you expect. Seekable input file brings no risk in this matter.
  - The actual reading of a block that is supposed to cover one logical sector of the device cannot give you a partial block. The device either reads the whole sector or nothing (read error). Note "a block that is supposed to cover one logical sector" requires the proper size *and* offset, it cannot start in the middle of a sector. In your case these conditions are met.

---

#### Improvement

`tar` creates archives with two 512-byte blocks filled with binary zeros as an end-of-file marker. This means it's later able to detect where the archive ends, it can easily ignore any trailing garbage. In addition it stores metadata (path, permissions etc.), is not limited to one file, can store directories… There is some overhead because of this, still the following procedure seems promising:

Archive `my.txt`:

```
tar -cf my.txt.tar my.txt
```

Write the archive to the device:

```
dd if=my.txt.tar of=/dev/sdb obs=512 seek=2099199
```

Or you can do both steps in a pipeline, without creating `my.txt.tar`:

```
tar -cf - my.txt | dd of=/dev/sdb obs=512 seek=2099199
```

(Note the archive is larger than the original file. Sole end-of-file marker will take 1 KiB. If there is data somewhere after the chosen sector, then you should take this into consideration. Creating `my.txt.tar` and comparing its size with the available space is the way to go before you use `dd`.)

Anyway, to retrieve the original file invoke:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb ibs=512 skip=2099199 | tar -xf -
```

That's it. You don't need to remember its size or name. And you can do anything that `tar` can do with any archive piped to its stdin; e.g. you can list the contents:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb ibs=512 skip=2099199 | tar -tvf -
```